# How to add existing project to VS2013 from Github

Tags: visual-studio-2013, github, version-control

i have one project in Github. i just like to know how could i attach that project with my local VS2013 so i can work and commit and other team member too. i search google lot to know how to attach existing project to VS2013 from Github but no luck. so if anyone knows it then please share the idea. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you can find a good [step by step post](http://michaelcrump.net/setting-up-github-to-work-with-visual-studio-2013-step-by-step/) about how to configure a Github repository in Visual Studio 2013.

Answer (score 1):

Just clone the project in your favorite Git client, then open the project file in Visual Studio.

You don't need to do anything special.  (although you'll probably want to install a Git extension for VS)

Comment: i am working with VS2013 and i heard that it has all feature for git. so do i need to install any special tool too ? i can clone it in my local folder but after that how could i attach that project to remote github as a result when i made change then change should reflect in remote file in github. idea would help me. thanks

Comment: when i will open the project in VS ide then how could i attach that project to git source control? sorry i have no idea how to achieve it.

Comment: @Mou: After making your changes, commit, then push using your favorite Git client.

Comment: There are a number of Git extensions in the VS extension gallery.  All they do is put a git client within VS; you can also operate without them.

Comment: is there any good tutorial which help me to learn the basics of Git? i need a easy tutorial. thanks

Comment: i need to know what git pull, push, bash etc meaning and their features. thanks. please help